# In Travis CI, How to run script to build the project with sudo

Tags: linux, maven, travis-ci

I am trying to build my project in travis ci server. Below is the `travis.yml`.

```
sudo: required
language: java
jdk: oraclejdk7
cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/.m2
install: true
before_script:
- Xvfb :99 &
- export DISPLAY=:99
script: sudo mvn clean package
```

However, the build is failing with the following error.

```
sudo: mvn: command not found
The command "sudo mvn clean package -Poss-travis-ci" exited with 1.
```

Please suggest a way to run a command with sudo privilege in Travis CI server.

Comment: Ask the operators of travis...i have my doubts that you will be allowed to run mvn via sudo. For what do you need to run sudo?

Comment: Operators of Travis redirected here to ask queries. I am using Arquillian to test my application which write some files in /var folder while deploying the application

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same issue. The following should solve it:

```
script:
  - sudo /usr/local/maven/bin/mvn clean package
```

Apparently the `mvn` executable, being located in `/usr/local`, is not in root's `PATH`. Therefore you must provide the executable's full path if running with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
script: 
   - sudo mvn clean package
   - sudo mvn install
```

Referencing: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java/#Projects-Using-Maven